# Sending response body with Akka?

Tags: reactjs, scala, akka

I have a Scala/akka-http project that has a reactjs frontend.  My route looks like this:

```
val quoteRoute = cors(){
    pathPrefix("quote") {
        get {
          complete (HttpResponse(201, entity=
            repository.
              shuffleQuotes(starterQuotes)
          ))
        }
        }
    }
```

This all works fine, and it prints out a string.  However, I have a react frontend that fetches the response like this:

```
function fetchQuote() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/quote", {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("quote not generated" + err)
        });
}
```

When I console.log the response, it gets relevant things like the status code.  But it says that bodyused is false, and I cannot find the actual string I want.  I'm not sure what the issue is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely need something like this:

```
function fetchQuote() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/quote", {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }) 
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("quote not generated" + err)
        });
}
```